# UWP: Using ToastNotificationActionTriggerDetail in javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, uwp, win-universal-app

I made a toast notification which contains a button that can be activated in background. This is the XML of the toast what I made and the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQRDo.png).

```
<toast launch="reopen">
  <visual>
    <binding template="ToastGeneric">
      <text>Test</text>
      <text>An toast command test</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
  <actions>
    <action content="Run" activationType="background" arguments="runtest"/>
  </actions>
</toast>
```

And I also registered background task to run code when the 'Run' button clicked like this:

```
var backgroundBox = Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
backgroundBox.BackgroundExecutionManager.requestAccessAsync().then(function () {
    var taskBuilder = backgroundBox.BackgroundTaskBuilder();
    taskBuilder.taskEntryPoint = "js\\backgroundTask.js";
    taskBuilder.name = "toastReportError";
    taskBuilder.setTrigger(new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.ToastNotificationActionTrigger());
    return taskBuilder.register();
});
```

My goal is to get the string of triggered action in the toast(in this case, "runtest" is the one to get). It seems like I need to use [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationActionTriggerDetail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationactiontriggerdetail.aspx), but when I called in backgroundTask.js, it threw an error: *type is not constructible*. Also, I've tried using Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs, but that also threw an error *[object Object]*.

I've googled and there was an example how to do this in C#, not javascript.

```
public sealed class NotificationActionBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as ToastNotificationActionTriggerDetail;

        if (details != null)
        {
            string arguments = details.Argument;
            var userInput = details.UserInput;

            // Perform tasks
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I can replace backgroundTask.js with backgroundTask.cs and use C# to write background task, but I want to use javascript if possible.

How can I get toast notification's argument when activated in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how to access the toast's argument. It can be accessed at `Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIBackgroundTaskInstance.current.triggerDetails.argument`.

Comment: That's great. This answer will be helpful to other community members.