# how to run code when Microsoft toast notification button is pressed in javascript

Tags: visual-studio-2017, toast, winjs

I am trying to make a microsoft toast notification that has buttons or so called "actions"
in this code i have 3 buttons A,B,C and i want to check if any of them are clicked and if so the run a line of code
just for example if A is clicked then run debug.log('A') 
how can i do that?
(im new to visual studio and javascript)

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
    var notifLib = Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;

    var toastContent = new notifLib.ToastContent();
    var toastVisual = new notifLib.ToastVisual();
    var toastBindingGeneric = new notifLib.ToastBindingGeneric();

    var adaptiveText = new notifLib.AdaptiveText();
    adaptiveText.text = "Hello World";
    toastBindingGeneric.children.push(adaptiveText);

    adaptiveText = new notifLib.AdaptiveText();
    adaptiveText.text = "This is a simple toast message";
    toastBindingGeneric.children.push(adaptiveText);

    toastVisual.bindingGeneric = toastBindingGeneric;

    toastContent.visual = toastVisual;

    var toastActionsCustom = new notifLib.ToastActionsCustom();

    var toastButton = new notifLib.ToastButton("a", "action=at&userId=1");
    toastButton.activationType = notifLib.ToastActivationType.background;
    toastActionsCustom.buttons.push(toastButton);

    toastButton = new notifLib.ToastButton("b", "action=b&userId=1");
    toastButton.activationType = notifLib.ToastActivationType.background;
    toastActionsCustom.buttons.push(toastButton);

    toastButton = new notifLib.ToastButton("c", "action=b&userId=1");
    toastButton.activationType = notifLib.ToastActivationType.background;
    toastActionsCustom.buttons.push(toastButton);

    toastContent.actions = toastActionsCustom;

    // Create the toast notification
    var toastNotif = new Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification(toastContent.getXml());

    // And send the notification
    Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.createToastNotifier().show(toastNotif);
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133302/ This might help your situation.

Answer (score 0):

for UWP applications, when the notification button is pressed, the `activated` event of the application will be triggered. In javascript, it can be written like this:

```js
Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("activated", function (activatedEventArgs) {
     if (activatedEventArgs.kind == Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.toastNotification) {
          console.log(activatedEventArgs.argument);
     }
});
```

If you are using WinJs to build your application, you can find the corresponding code block that handles the click of the Toast notification in the `app.onactivated` event in **main.js**

```js
...
else if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
    if (args.detail.arguments) {
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: the problem im having is that i dont know how to use it on a specific button cause i have 3 Toastbuttons so how would i be able to specify like `if toastbutton A is pressed ? ` (sorry if this looks dumb im really new to javascript)

Comment: When you defined `ToastButton`, you gave a series of parameters (such as `action=a&userId=1`). When you click the button A, the **actived** event of the application will be triggered, and this parameter will be passed in (`args.detail.arguments`). You can determine which button was pressed according to the incoming parameters in the `actived` event callback (such as Different actions to judge)

Comment: ` Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("activated", function (activatedEventArgs) {
    if (activatedEventArgs.kind == Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.A) {
        
    }
});`                                                                                                                                               it wont run did i misunderstand something ?

Comment: i changed the definiton of the A toastbutton to only be A and not action=a&userId=1

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you mean by `only be A`. When you defined `ToastButton`, you passed in two parameters, one is the display content of the Button, and the other is the parameter attached to the Button. After the application is activated, parameters will be passed in, so we need to set some identifiers in the parameters, such as `action=A`. But before that, you may consider setting `toastButton.activationType` to `notifLib.ToastActivationType.foreground`, which will activate the application.

Comment: i meant it by deleting the t&userId=1 part of action=at&userId=1 cause i used notification visualizer to generate the code and it was based of a friend request example or something like that and i want it to run in the backround mostly so i dont think i need foreground activation type but now im kinda confused so where do i specify that im looking for action=A when the toastbuttons get activated?

Comment: Hello, activation using the background method requires you to create a background task and listen for the "backgroundActivated" event in main.js. Through your description, you may create the Winjs application. If so, the relevant events are not provided in WinJS.Application, you can't get this parameter through the background. If you insist on using the background method, the WinJS application may not be applicable. You need to create a WebHost application (PWA) and use `Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication` as the application main

Comment: would it be possible for it to only go into the foreground when the notification opens?

Comment: If you are using a WinJS application, you may not be able to handle the activation of toast from the background because the corresponding event is missing.